# How to deploy python extensions (shared libraries) with multiple architectures?

Tags: python, python-c-api

Context: one can compile C code such that it can be used as a Python module. The compiled object is a shared library with a specific naming, so Python can find and load it as a module.

Great. I have successfully compiled and tested code such that file "foo.c" becomes a shared library "foo.so", and Python code `import foo` works.

The goal is to distribute a set of shared libraries for Mac, Linux, and Windows, where `import foo` loads the appropriate shared library.

Conceptually, I want my distribution to contain a directory with three files:

```
mypkg/
  ┠─ __init__.py
  ┠─ foo.so    (linux)
  ┠─ foo.dylib (mac)
  ┖─ foo.dll   (windows)
```

so that `from mypkg import foo` picks the appropriate library.
I **do not** want to distribute the source code `foo.c`.

The problem is, Mac will pick the `.so` file and complain:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/.../mypkg/foo.so, 0x0002): tried: '/.../mypkg/foo.so' (not a mach-o file)
```

Is there a pattern / naming scheme which would permit this (short of writing a custom module loader)?

**Edit**: Explanation why PyPI / pip / wheel-type distribution is not desired... these aren't running in a standard python.exe process.

The *main executable* is a C program, which enables C-language plugins using an SDK. I've written a C plugin, which provides Python and exposes a Python interface to the original C API (doing `Py_Initialize()` etc. This C extension looks for, loads, and executes Python plugins. The result is one can now write Python plugins instead of C plugins. Users place Python plugins in a specific directory & each is read and executed. (plugins cannot execute standalone.) That all works fine.

Now, I'm looking at how one of these plugins can define and use a shared library Python module.

```
main.c -> 1) InitPython
          2) PyImport_Import("plugins/a.py")
          3) PyImport_Import("plugins/b.py")
               -> import mypkg.foo
             ...
```

If mypkg/foo.py is pure Python, this works great. If foo is a shared library, then it must be named `foo.so` on Linux and macOS, so I cannot simply ship my plugin as `b.py` + `mypkg/*`. I might be able to use `pip install --target=plugins foo.whl`.

Alternatively I'm testing a different loading mechanism, similar to @shadowtalker's non-recommendation, for `mypkg/foo.py`:

```
import os
import platform
_system = platform.system()

from importlib.machinery import ExtensionFileLoader
from importlib.utils import spec_from_file_location

filename = f'{os.path.dirname(__file__)/foo.{_system.lower()}.so'
_loader = ExtensionFileLoader('foo', filename)
_spec = spec_from_file_location('foo', filename)
_mod = _loader.create_module(_spec)
_loader.exec_module(_mod)
from foo import *
```

It looks like it's working, but I'll continue to test.

Answer (score 2):

This is handled by the binary package distribution format called Wheel: https://pythonwheels.com/

You will end up building one a separate wheel for each platform, and each wheel will contain only the .so/.dylib/.dll files that are needed for that particular platform.

Just about every major library in the Python ecosystem today distributes their code in the wheel format, even those that do not use compiled extensions.

If you are using a PEP-517-compatible build backend (Setuptools, Flit, Hatch,  Poetry) building a wheel is as simple as `pip install build && python -m build`. This will produce a wheel file with a standardized filename, which can be uploaded directly to PyPI for distribution. When end users want to install your package, Pip will download the version of the wheel that is compatible with the user's system.

However, this will not handle cross-compiling for multiple platforms. For that, you will need something like a container or VM, or a tool like [cibuildwheel](https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Note that the details of how to set up your particular build backend to compile an extension, or to include existing compiled artifacts in the wheel, will vary considerably depending on the build backend you are using.

Finally, if you're unfamiliar with the concept of a "PEP 517 build backend", see here for a brief explanation and a tutorial for using Setuptools: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/build_meta.html

Comment: I'll investigate wheels, but I think it has added distribution complexity. In this case, I'd have three wheels (one per architecture) and have to upload to PyPI (or other hosted site). It's true, the user would easily install with pip....but that's still an additional step... Yes, it _works_ which I suppose beats the alternative.

Comment: @pbuck You already need to cross-compile your binary extension, so presumably you already have some kind of VM setup or cloud CI setup for doing that. I'd say that's probably the hardest part. Once that's done, it's just a matter of uploading 3 files to PyPI instead of 1, and you can upload them all at once with a single command using the Twine tool. See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi. On the user side of things, there's arguably *less* complexity, because `pip install` should "just work".

Answer (score 2):

If for whatever reason the [officially-recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592810/2954547) tools and techniques don't work for you (or if you just prefer to do things the hard way), your other option is to give each compiled extension a *different module name*, and then dynamically import the correct one based on [`platform.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system) or similar:

```
mypkg/
  ┠─ __init__.py
  ┠─ foo.py
  ┠─ _foo_linux.so
  ┠─ _foo_mac.dylib
  ┖─ _foo_win.dll
```

And in `foo.py`:

```py
import platform

_system = platform.system()

if _system == "Linux":
    from ._foo_linux import *
elif _system == "Darwin":
    from ._foo_mac import *
elif _system == "Windows":
    from ._foo_win import *
else:
    raise RuntimeError(f"Unsupported system: {_system!r}")
```

However you would still want to distribute this as a wheel, since you are shipping binary artifacts. At which point you're better off building separate wheels for each platform, which removes the burden from you to get this right, and generally will work better with the rest of the ecosystem.

In case it wasn't clear from my tone and comments in the other answer: **I do not recommend doing this.**

There might be other niche use cases for this kind of dynamic dispatching behavior (e.g. checking for the presence of a command or shared library in on the user's system). So hopefully this answer still serves as a useful example for someone out there, even though I think it's the wrong answer for the particular question that was asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Summarizing and providing "my" solution.

1. Wheel is a great approach, if distribution can be via pip. Wheels can include binaries without source code & installation selects the correct architecture. Unfortunately, that doesn't fit my deployment environment, so I can't use that.
2. Using `importlib.machinery`, as described in the original query works, but seems too "clever" to be a good idea: There's a simpler solution.
3. I'm sure there's a way using a fancier combination of `importlib.machinery` with custom `PathFinder` could be done. (See also https://github.com/soroco/pyce/tree/master for custom loader example.) But it's like #2: overkill.
4. Using the pattern described by @shadowtalker is simple and workable, with a couple of notes:

   a. Instead of `from _foo_linux import *`, use relative import `from ._foo_linux import *`, so make sure the local shared library is loaded.

   b. Exact same `C` source code can be used to compile all three architectures: Note that the shared library filename MUST match the module being loaded....

Three different shared library filenames, means three different modules. But (what I hadn't thought of) you can include all three `PyMODINIT_FUNC` in the same file, all creating the module using the same `PyModuleDef`:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_foo_linx(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&foo_module);
}
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_foo_windows(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&foo_module);
}
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_foo_darwin(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&foo_module);
}
```

The build code simply compiles the same code and names the Darwin compilation `foo_darwin.so`; the Windows compilation `foo_windows.dll`, and the Linux compilation `foo_linux.so`.

This way, `import .foo_darwin`, loads the shared object, and invokes the `PyInit_foo_darwin()` function; `import .foo_linux` loads and invokes the `PyInit_foo_linux()` function, etc.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error in my import syntax, I updated it in my answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
import platform

_system = platform.system()

if _system == "Linux":
    from _foo_linux import *
elif _system == "Darwin":
    from _foo_mac import *
elif _system == "Windows":
    from _foo_win import *
else:
    raise RuntimeError(f"Unsupported system: {_system!r}")
```

Comment: This appears to just be a copy-pasted fragment of [shadowtalker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77592932/11082165). What is this answer supposed to add?